# Cursor stuck in select mode

Tags: mouse, cursor

I have sometime problem with select mode in the mouse. The cursor is stuck in select mode, 
so I can not click anything , to solve that I need to reboot my laptop

my laptop is :

- sony vaio
- model : VGN-CS320j

I note that problem since ubuntu 11.04 , and it still happens in 11.10. So, I would like to know if that problem have been reported or not.

Comment: Does pressing ESC during this problem get you out of select mode?

Comment: You may have activated some accessibility options with a key-combination. Try turning them off on gnome-control-center, section "assistive technologies", button "keyboard accesibility", tab "accesibility".

Comment: Have a look on this thread, maybe it could help you too: [Sony VAIO VPC-S12L9E/B TouchPad not working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1565548)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

From the above thread

Edit `/etc/default/grub` , you may need to boot to recovery mode to make the edit.

```
# Command line 
sudo -e /etc/default/grub

# Graphical
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" to look lilke this

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"

Update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

If that does not solve the problem I suggest you file a bug report.

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)